# Color plot of $x^4 + y^4 + z^4$ over the unit sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$

Tags: plotting, color

I want to color plot the function $x^4 + y^4 + z^4$ over the unit sphere. What I tried is

```
f[u_, v_] := (Cos[u] Sin[v])^4 + (Sin[u] Sin[v])^4 + Cos[v]^4 
ParametricPlot3D[
  {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{u, v}, Hue[f[u, v]]]]
```

I think that this is wrong, since the function is even and so the opposite points on the sphere should have the same color, however the output is

[image]

Where did I go wrong? Any ideas on how to make this work? I don't know if `Hue` is the right function here, but basically the function $x^4 + y^4 + z^4$ has range $[0,1]$ and I want something that translates the value of the function into some kind of color scheme, to visualise the function.

Comment: Something like `SliceContourPlot3D[x^4 + y^4 + z^4, "CenterSphere", {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]`?

Comment: The arguments to a `ColorFunction` function in `ParametricPlot3D` are `x, y, z, u, v` (as per the doc page for `ColorFunction`).  The other problem is you probably want `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!